# Migrating database into a newer version of civicrm?

Tags: migration

I have tried importing the database from a production server running civicrm 4.4 into a development server running 4.7 - but it appears that only contact names are present - email, address, activities, memberships and contributions are all missing.
Does this mean that I need to start again, downgrade civicrm to 4.4 on the dev server and only upgrade it after porting the database?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to migrate the complete database you should indeed do the following:

1. Set your old environment in read-only maintenance mode
2. Set up the new environment (CiviCRM & CMS) using exactly the same versions
3. Migrate the databases
4. Update CiviCRM and CMS to the latest versions
5. Properly test (quite some changes between 4.4. and 4.7)
6. Go-Live or rollback

As an alternative (if your data isn't too complex) you could export everything you need as csv-files and either use the UI import function of CiviCRM to import into the new environment or give [Eileen's import extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui/11) a shot.